# Raspberry Pi 3 cannot see Ubuntu hotspot

Tags: networking, wireless, hot-spot

I want to connect my pi3 wirelessly, for that i need a hotspot wifi. But hotspot should be on laptop which is Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on it. When i try to scan all wifi on Pi it can see only Windows-Android etc. I tried all channels to make Pi can see the Ubuntu's wifi, but Pi still cannot see Wi-Fi Hotspot on Ubuntu(btw other devices can see Ubuntu's Wi-Fi). I already can use 12-13 when i check wlan0 channels. (I already set wifi country IE on raspi-config)

Could you help me please to figure this problem ?

I guess something wrong on subnet "10.42.0.0". Somehow Pi doesn't recognize it.

Edit: With same laptop on windows 10 hotspot option can visible on Pi3 as well.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see what band, not channel, is being used on your hotspot.  The Raspberry Pi 3 only has a 2.4Ghz radio.  If you're publishing your hotspot using 5Ghz, it will not see it.

Comment: I already checked, hotspot band is 2.4.